# Xgboost multiple class predictive performance beats one versus rest

Tags: nlp, xgboost, prediction, performance

I have an NLP task I'm tackling with xgboost (R implementation).

Before describing my doubt I'll give you some background:

I have a corpus of documents for which I did topic discovery, using a term x term matrix clustering approach. For each document, I get a topic score computed using the terms in the document (with a TfIdf score). Then for each document, I pick up the topic with the highest score.

The following step is to create a model that given the term x document score matrix and the best topic per document, predicts the best topic.

I tried two different approaches:

- a multiple class model, where a topic is associated with each document;
- a one versus rest series of models, one per topic, where each document is labeled as belonging or not to a topic.

Here are the results of the two approaches, using AUC:

```
    i                 topic    single     multi
1   1             Topic.nv1 0.9564445 0.9880821
2   2  Topic.nv10_Topic.wv9 0.9848492 0.9969546
3   3            Topic.nv11 0.9174293 0.9741100
4   4 Topic.nv12_Topic.wv11 0.9874073 0.9967725
5   5 Topic.nv13_Topic.wv10 0.9509909 0.9916768
6   6 Topic.nv14_Topic.wv12 0.9864622 0.9959161
7   7            Topic.nv15 0.7333333 0.9333333
8   8   Topic.nv2_Topic.wv3 0.9590279 0.9877953
9   9   Topic.nv3_Topic.wv5 0.9448966 0.9879057
10 10   Topic.nv4_Topic.wv2 0.9521490 0.9908656
11 11   Topic.nv5_Topic.wv6 0.9761665 0.9946294
12 12             Topic.nv6 0.9439377 0.9889028
13 13   Topic.nv7_Topic.wv4 0.9656248 0.9926163
14 14             Topic.nv8 0.9673726 0.9944970
15 15   Topic.nv9_Topic.wv8 0.9716538 0.9929586
16 16             Topic.wv1 0.9610704 0.9925414
17 17             Topic.wv7 0.9765398 0.9904255
```

It is visible that the multiclass approach systematically outperforms the one vs rest one. NB: These are training set performances.

Is there a clear theoretical reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiclass models in XGBoost consist of `n_classes` separate forests, one for each one-vs-rest binary problem.  At each iteration, an extra tree is added to each forest.  But it isn't actually a one-vs-rest approach (as I thought in the first version of this answer), because these trees are built to minimize a single loss function, the cross-entropy of the softmax probabilities.
https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/multiclassification-training-process/29
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/806
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3655

In general, the one-vs-rest models are very good at identifying the single class, whereas the multiclass model has to balance performance on all of them.  More specifically, I think that the softmax may be responsible for the phenomenon you're displaying.  *(I'm still thinking about it, but I thought I should post the above for now.)*

Suppose one of your documents is reasonably likely to be in either of two topics: the probability scores given by the forests are 0.9, 0.85, then <0.1 in all the rest.  In your topic-1 model, you make a fairly confident judgement that this document is of topic 1 (score of 0.9).  But in the multiclass ensemble, you see things as much more uncertain; maybe the model applies softmax, so that the probability of topic 1 is only ~0.5.

More extreme, suppose the individual topic model scores are all 0.9.  Now the multiclass ensemble applies softmax and produces equal 1/17 probabilities for each topic!

In the other direction, suppose one of your documents is judged unlikely to fit *any* of the topics: all the individual topic model probability scores are 0.01.  In the multiclass ensemble, that gets scaled up to 1/17 (OK, 17 topics makes this a harder sell).

---

Hrm, except how likely is it to get the 0.9 and 0.85, since a training sample in one of these two topics will be pushed toward 0 by the other model... ?  Especially when your scores are fairly high, so it's not like the models have huge blind spots.
*(This part still causes a problem with the correct understanding of how XGBoost works; the log-loss of the softmax probabilities still penalizes being confident about belonging to two different classes...)*

Comment: uhm, ok I'm not sure I follow. Is the fact that xgboost use one-vs-rest models also for multivariate problems documented? By "in parallel" you mean as in "parallel computing" or as in "multivariate joined estimation". Because the following explanation seems to be related to the multivariate estimation. I also do not understand the rest of the explanation about the smoothing of the predicted probabilities in the multivariate case and how this leads to better predictions.

Comment: Ah, so I was wrong about the models being built "in parallel", by which I just meant "independently" (though that would make parallel computing easy).  I'll edit a bit.